# How to only keep counties crossed by a motorway?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, spatial, r-sf

I am newish to R and very new to GIS plotting on R with sf and ggplot2 packages. I have a dataset "comuni" containing all communes in Italy (similar to counties) and one of all motorways in Italy called "only_motorway". I know that I can use certain regions as a cookie cutter and keep only the motorways that are contained within such regions using st_intersection() function. However, I would like to do the inverse where, given I have a shapefile of the A3 motorway, I would like to keep only those communes that are crossed by that specific motorway.

I've tried using st_intersection function in the following way:

```
only_motorway_A3 <- only_motorway %>%
  filter(ref == "A3")

comuni_A3 <- st_intersection(only_motorway_A3,comuni)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = comuni_A3, 
          color = "black", size = 0.1, fill = "black") +
  geom_sf(data = only_motorway_A3, size = 0.15, color = "green") +
  coord_sf(crs = 32632) +  
  theme_void()
```

But the results is the picture below:

[ggplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oun6Q.png)

ie both only_motorway_A3 and comuni_A3 have the same geometry column and they both plot the highway line. What I wanted to plot instead was the highway line (in green) from only_motoway_A3 and all around it the communes crossed by it (in black) from comuni_A3. I hope it is clear and thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: I think you want `st_intersects` instead of `st_intersection`. If you use `st_intersects` you will get a logical vector of true and false that will allow you to subset `comuni`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a `sf::st_join()` call, using first your polygons and secondly your line string objects, with parameter `left` set to false.

It will perform an inner (filtering) spatial join of the two objects. Only those polygons (the first argument) that contain a motorway will be retained.